# Валидация формы html

Tags: html, css

Можно средствами html css, сделать так чтобы в форму поля можно было ввести только такие данные?

- Дата рождения (формат в форме дд.мм.гггг)
- СНИЛС (формат xxx-xxx-xxx xx, только цифры)
- Полис ОМС (16 символов, только цифры)

Сама форма стандартная: исключение подключен бутстрап для сетки:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Форма для отправки данных на сервер</title>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Форма</h1>
            <p>Простая форма</p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="https://www.google.ru" role="button">Узнать больше &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded;" id="contact-form" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">
            <div class="form-group" id="name-field">
                <label for="form-name" class="col-lg-2 control-label"><?php  ?></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-name" name="form-name" placeholder="<?php  ?>" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="email-field">
                <label for="form-email" class="col-lg-2 control-label"><?php  ?></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="form-email" name="form-email" placeholder="<?php  ?>" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="subject-field">
                <label for="form-subject" class="col-lg-2 control-label"><?php  ?></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form-subject" name="form-subject" placeholder="<?php  ?>" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" id="message-field">
                <label for="form-message" class="col-lg-2 control-label"><?php ?></label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="6" id="form-message" name="form-message" placeholder="<?php ?>" required></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-10">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><?php ?></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: через pattern https://webref.ru/html/input/pattern

Comment: А что у Вас получилось в поисках решения?

Comment: вот сюда и пришёл за решением, помню вроде видел что то , а как найти не знаю. помогли добрые люди

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С версии 5, html поддерживает для input свойство pattern, которое с помощью `регулярных выражений` позволяет на уровне html осуществлять валидацию полей ввода, а так же определять стили валидных и невалидных введенных данных на css с помощью псевдоэлемента `:valid`. Например:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[\d]{1,}">
```

Этот код не позвонит предать обработчику по нажатию кнопки submit введенную в поле ввода информацию, если введено это менее одной цифры. А поддерживающий `pattern` браузер проиндицирует ошибку всплывающим сообщением и цветом окантовки `input`.

Советую изучить регулярные выражения, они имеют особенности для php/html и js. А так же обратить внимание на безопасность ваших полей ввода - злоумышленник скорее всего будет обращаться напрямую к вашему обрабочику, минуя валидацию на уровне html и js. Поэтому в обработчике все равно придется проводить повторную валидацию.

Answer (score 1):

Используй `mask` для `input`. ***Пример***:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#data').mask('99/99/9999');
  $('#snils').mask('9999-9999-9999-9999');
  $('#16numbers').mask('9999999999999999');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.0/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input id="data" type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' pattern="^([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{2})\/([0-9]{4})$" placeholder="01/02/2016" required>
  <input id="snils" type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}" placeholder="9999-9999-9999-9999" required>
    <input id="16numbers" type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57' pattern="[0-9]{16}" placeholder="9999999999999999" required>
  <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Для ввода только цифр используй атрибут `onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'`.

Для правильной работы поля ввода даты используй [DateEntry](http://keith-wood.name/dateentry.html), не могу дописать здесь, CDN не смог найти...

Comment: Не знал что дата может быть `55/45/4846`.

Comment: @Other Я написал общий пример, как это работает, уважаемый, oTHER.

Comment: @Nikita Smith Один вопрос уважаемый, если я таким образом задаю маски, то какие значение (value) будут у инпутов? Т.е. пользователь ввёл 99999999 - в поле отобразилось 99/99/9999 - а какое значение у поля получается 99999999  ?

Comment: @stas0k нет, вы не правы, значение такое же какое вы видите)

Comment: @stas0k помогло?

Comment: не очень, хотелось бы без jQuery